# kentico youtube webpart used within slick.js

Tags: kentico, slick.js, youtube-iframe-api

I have a repeater that out puts panels for a slide show plugin, slick.js. So far, things are working as planned.

The user, when creating the custom page, enters in copy, then either and image, video from the media library, or a link to you tube.

What i'm trying to do is write the JS function that will fire when the user clicks play on the youtube video.

The webpart injects the youtube video via the iFrame method.

Here's my transformation:

```html
<section class="slide">
    <div class="copy">
        <%# Eval("SlideContent") %>
    </div>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat='server' id='slideImage' visible='<%# IfEmpty( Eval("SlideImage"), false, true )  %>'>
        <div class="img">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="<%# Eval(" SlideImage ") %>" alt="<%# Eval(" SlideContent ") %>">
        </div>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat='server' id='slideVideo' visible='<%# IfEmpty( Eval("SlideVideo"), false, true )  %>'>
        <div class='videoHolder html5'>
            <video id='video' class='html5Video' controls>
                <source src='<%# Eval("SlideVideo") %>'>
            </video>
        </div>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat='server' id='youTubeVideo' visible='<%# IfEmpty( Eval("YouTubeVideo"), false, true )  %>'>
        <%@ Register Src="~/CMSWebParts/Media/YouTubeVideo.ascx" TagName="YoutubeVideo" TagPrefix="webPart" %>
            <div class='videoHolder yt'>
                <webPart:YoutubeVideo runat="server" id="YouTubeVideoWebpart" CssClass="ytVideo" VideoURL='<%# ResolveMacros(Eval("YouTubeVideo").ToString())%>' FullScreen='true' />
            </div>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
</section>
```

And here is my JS (this also includes the code to pause videos if the slider changes)

```js
$(function () {
  'use strict';
  var $slider = $('.slider'),
    $slickJS = '/kffIntranet/ui/bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js';

  // we check for a slider on the page
  if ($slider.length !== 0) {

    // if there is a slider, we load the slick.js plugin
    $.getScript($slickJS, function () {
      // init  the slider
      $slider.slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        fade: false,
        lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 5000,
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 1024,
            settings: {}
          }, {
            breakpoint: 600,
            settings: {}
          }, {
            breakpoint: 480,
            settings: {
              arrows: false
            }
          }
          // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
          // settings: "unslick"
          // instead of a settings object
        ]
      });
    });

    //

    // video control. If a slide has video, we need to pause

    //bind our event here, it gets the current slide and pauses the video before each slide changes.
    $slider.on('beforeChange', function (event, slick) {
      var currentSlide, player, command, videoType;

      //find the current slide element and decide which player API we need to use.
      currentSlide = $(slick.$slider).find('.slick-current');

      //determine which type of slide this by looking for the video holder than getting the video type class
      if (currentSlide.find('.videoHolder').length) {
        videoType = $('.videoHolder', currentSlide).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
        //get the iframe inside this slide.
        player = currentSlide.find('iframe').get(0);
      }
      // pause videos
      if (videoType === 'yt') {
        command = {
          'event': 'command',
          'func': 'pauseVideo'
        };
        player.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(command), '*');
      } else if (videoType === 'html5') {
        document.getElementById('video').pause();
      }

    });

    // pause slider if a video is playing
    // html 5 video click
    $('.html5Video').on('click', function () {
      var $video = $(this).get(0);
      // control pause play state of video
      if ($video.paused) {
        $video.play();
      } else {
        $video.pause();
      }
      // call slide pause function
      pauseSlide();
    });
    // youtube play
    $('.ytVideo iframe').on('click', function () {
      // call slide pause function
      pauseSlide();
    });
  }

  // puse slider function
  function pauseSlide() {
    $slider.slick('slickPause');
    console.log('pause');
  }
});
```

So i've created a function pauseSlide that will pause the slider, but i'm struggling with capturing the youtube play click.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this answer out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29641751/698678).  It suggests using the YouTube iframe API.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script> </head> <body> <div id='vidWrapper'> <!-- The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. --> <div id="ytplayer"></div> </div> <script> var player; function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() { player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', { height: '390', width: '640', videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE', events: { 'onStateChange': function(event) { if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) { pauseAudio(); } } } }); } function pauseAudio() { ... } </script> </body> </html>
```

Comment: I've been looking at that. Not using the Kentico webpart, and going pure JS. Enter in just the video ID, add that as a data attribute on a div in the transformation, and then the JS.

Comment: Yeah I'd highly suggest not embedding a webpart within a webpart.  A control within a webpart is fine but typically not a webpart.  The plain html for an iframe should be just fine

Comment: Or maybe they really don't need a youtube video in slider.... lol... ok thanks. i'll let you know how this goes.

Comment: We created this component before slick slider was there using Repeater transformation + JS. It works really well. let me know if you need any help with the code?

Comment: Thanks Chetan. I have it working, just some kenitco form validation and cross browser checks. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i took a step back in this. The transformation now looks for a YouTube ID and then i have a jQuery plugin take over.

So the slider auto playes, and if a video (either youtube, or mp4) is started, the slider stops. Also, if either of the slider direction arrows, or one of the pips are clicked, the video will pause.

I still need to refactor and add some logic, but it's working.

Here's the updated transformation:

```html
<section class="slide">
    <div class="copy">
        <%# Eval("SlideContent") %>
    </div>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat='server' id='slideImage' visible='<%# IfEmpty( Eval("SlideImage"), false, true )  %>'>
        <div class="img">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="<%# Eval(" SlideImage ") %>" alt="<%# Eval(" SlideContent ") %>">
        </div>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat='server' id='slideVideo' visible='<%# IfEmpty( Eval("SlideVideo"), false, true )  %>'>
        <div class='videoHolder html5'>
            <video id='video' class='html5Video' controls>
                <source src='<%# Eval("SlideVideo") %>'>
            </video>
        </div>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat='server' id='youTubeVideoID' visible='<%# IfEmpty( Eval("YouTubeVideoID"), false, true )  %>'>      
      <div class='videoHolder yt' data-vID='<%# Eval("YouTubeVideoID") %>'>
        <div class="vh"></div>
      </div>      
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
</section>
```

my video.js file

```js
$(function () {
  'use strict';

  var vHolder = $('.videoHolder'),
    vtPlugin = '/kffIntranet/ui/scripts/plugins/tubePlayer/jQuery.tubeplayer.min.js',
    vID;

  // check for a youtube video, and if there is one, load the youtube pluging
  if ($('.yt').length) {
    // load plugin
    $.getScript(vtPlugin, function () {
      // once plugin is loaded, loop through each YT and call the plugin
      $('.yt').each(function (i, v) {
        var $this = $(this);
        vID = $this.attr('data-vid');

        $('.vh', $this).tubeplayer({
          initialVideo: vID,
          onPlayerPlaying: function () {
            $('.slider').slick('slickPause');
          }
        });
      });
    });
  } else if ($('.html5').length) {
    $('.html5 .html5video').bind('pause', function () {
      $('.slider').slick('slickPause');
    });
  }

});
```

and my slider js file

```js
$(function () {
  'use strict';
  var $slider = $('.slider'),
    $slickJS = '/kffIntranet/ui/bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js',
    videoType;

  // we check for a slider on the page
  if ($slider.length !== 0) {

    // if there is a slider, we load the slick.js plugin
    $.getScript($slickJS, function () {
      // init  the slider
      $slider.slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        fade: false,
        lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 5000,
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 1024,
            settings: {}
          }, {
            breakpoint: 600,
            settings: {}
          }, {
            breakpoint: 480,
            settings: {
              arrows: false
            }
          }
          // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
          // settings: "unslick"
          // instead of a settings object
        ]
      });
    });
    // on slide change
    $slider.on('beforeChange', function (event, slick) {
      var currentSlide;
      //find the current slide element and decide which player API we need to use.
      currentSlide = $(slick.$slider).find('.slick-current');
      //determine which type of slide this by looking for the video holder than getting the video type class
      if (currentSlide.find('.videoHolder').length) {
        videoType = $('.videoHolder', currentSlide).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
      }
      // pause videos
      if (videoType === 'html5') {
        document.getElementById('video').pause();
      } else if (videoType === 'yt') {
        $('.vh', currentSlide).tubeplayer('pause');
      }
    });
  }
});
```