# Onclick event on Youtube embedded iframe?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm embedding a youtube video on my page using the following code:

```
<iframe width="400" height="300" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/video-url"</iframe>
```

I have a custom javascript event that is used to track and log events in general, using the following code:

```
var trackSomething = function(a, b, c){

    if(a&& a.trim() != ''){
        saveCustom(a, b);
    }

};
```

I want to use this function to track if users are actually clicking on that video in order to play it.

Normally I would add this code to the relevant tag:

`onclick="trackSomething('Play Video')"`

But I noticed that if I add an `onclick` event inside the `iframe` tag, it doesn't work, and neither if I wrap the `iframe` with a `span` or `div` and apply the event to these tags.

What's the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: Most likely best using the YouTube API, as answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640675/possible-to-add-an-onclick-event-to-a-youtube-iframe

Comment: ok thanks, I still can't make it work, [see this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39877757/execute-javascript-function-when-youtube-video-is-played-using-youtube-api)