# Execute JavaScript function when YouTube video is played (using YouTube API)

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

I'm embedding a youtube video on my page using the following code:

```
<iframe width="400" height="300" id="newvid" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/url?modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&feature=player_embedded&fs=0&iv_load_policy=3&rel=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I'm trying to use the Youtube API, so a javascript function will be executed once user is playing the video, but the following code doesn't work, as I don't see any alert showing when clicking the video:

```
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<script>
      var player;

      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('newvid', {
          events: {
            'onStateChange': function(event) {
              if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
                  myFunction();
              }
            }
          }
        });
      }
</script>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("I am an alert box!");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be set up with a div container rather than selecting the iFrame.
(This may not run correctly in the snippet container, however please try in your code).

```html
<div id="newvid"></div>

<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<script>
      var player;

      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('newvid', {
          height: '300',
          width: '400',
          videoId: 'SwxdBiazu8M', // Example video ID
          events: {
            'onStateChange': function(event) {
              if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
                  myFunction();
              }
            }
          }
        });
      }
</script>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("I am an alert box!");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, though if that's the only way, I suppose I must use accordingly the `playerVars` attribute to include all the parameters i'm using,

Answer (score 0):

Below code demonstrates and executes `JS function` using `enablejsapi` in `iframe` -

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YtF6p_w-cSc?autoplay=1&controls=0&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<script>
  // Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // Replace the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
  // YouTube player after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {  
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',      
      events: {
            'onStateChange': function(event) {
              if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
                  myFunction();
              }
            }
          }  
    });           
  }

  function myFunction() {
    alert("I am an alert box!");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/53nku8yw/)

As per the above code `JS function` will be called once the `playerstate` is `PLAYING`. Hope this will help you and you are looking for the same. Also, please let me know if you have any questions.

Thanks..!